# Scid vs Mac game interrupted

Tags: engines, scid

My Windows 7 Bootcamp partition failed me, so I'm using `Scid vs Mac OSX 10.9.5` app to test my engine. It works fine, but sometimes a tournament game is 'interrupted' and I don't know why. For example, in this game my engine was playing white:

1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nf6 3.Nxe5 Nxe4 4.Qe2 d6 5.Nxf7 Kxf7 6.Qxe4 d5 7.Qf3+ Kg8 8.Nc3 Be6 9.Qe3 Qf6 10.Nb5 Na6 11.Kd1 Bf7 12.d4 c6 13.Nc3 Nb4 14.a3 Re8 15.Qd2 Bh5+ 16.Be2 Bxe2+ 17.Nxe2 Na6 18.Qf4 Be7 19.Re1 Bd8 20.Be3 Qg6 21.Qg3 Qf5 22.Kc1 Bc7 23.f4 Kf7 24.Qf2 Rhf8 25.Ng3 Qg4 26.h3 Qh4 27.Ne2 Qxf2 28.Bxf2 Bd6 29.Bg3 Nc7 30.Kd1 Re4 31.Ra2 Rfe8 32.c3 c5 33.dxc5 Bxc5 34.f5 Nb5 35.a4 Nd6 36.b4 Nxf5 37.Rf1 Ke6 38.Rxf5 Kxf5 39.bxc5 Re3 40.Bf2 Rd3+ 41.Kc1 Kf6 42.Bd4+ Kf5 43.Bxg7 Rg8 
White movetime 0.033 secs

We see this message: "White movetime 0.033 secs". What does that mean?

Comment: Ok, why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out that my UCI protocol parsing had some nasty bugs, that's why all the Perft tests were ok, but the engine matches were buggy... ouch!

So it was not SCID's fault, sorry!